# Count how many locks required for a MySQL (InnoDB) query

Tags: mysql, innodb

I'm performance tuning a very data-heavy mysql application. It has a purge system that often seems to cause lock timeout errors for users. Based on my research I have a few adjustments to the query to make to ensure we're locking as few records as possible... but

Is there any way to get a count of how many records mysql will lock for a given query? I want to be able to see evidence that my adjustments are requiring fewer locks.

In this specific case, I have some subqueries for foreign key data since I can't use LIMIT and JOINs. I'm wondering what impact, if any, the subquery has on the delete query locking.

I'm also considering the "primary key chunking" described [here](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig).